# Instantiating a UIView subclass from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I found a tutorial that does exactly what I want to do in my existing Objective-C project, but it's written in Swift. I understand everything in Swift, but I'm having a nightmarish time "translating" a `UIView's` initializer to Objective-C. This should be really simple, but I can't figure it out.

My code doesn't crash, but it doesn't load anything. I put a breakpoint in my `UIViewController` to see what's happening when I try to load the `UIView` subclass and here's what I'm seeing:

```
(lldb) po self.boxSize
75

(lldb) po self.holderView.frame
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))
 (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 0, height = 0))

(lldb) po self.holderView
 nil
```

Here's the view I'm trying to "replicate" in Objective-C.

**HolderView.swift:**

```
class HolderView: UIView {

    var parentFrame :CGRect = CGRectZero

    weak var delegate:HolderViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = Colors.clear
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    // A bunch of class methods
}
```

Here are my "translated" Objective-C .h/.m files:

**HolderView.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol HolderViewDelegate <NSObject>
// delegate methods
@ end

@interface HolderView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <HolderViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic) CGRect frame;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect parentFrame;
```

**HolderView.m:**

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self.parentFrame = CGRectZero;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [super setFrame:self.parentFrame];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; // Added to see if it's working
        NSLog(@"anyone home?");
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is the code for the Swift & Objective-C `UIViewControllers` to add the `UIView`:

**ViewController.swift**

```
  func addHolderView() {
    let boxSize: CGFloat = 75.0
    holderView.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.width / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                              y: view.bounds.height / 2 - boxSize / 2,
                              width: boxSize,
                              height: boxSize)
    holderView.parentFrame = view.frame
    holderView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(holderView)
    holderView.addOval()
  }
```

Here's my "translated" Objective-C View Controller:

```
- (void)addHolderView {
    self.boxSize = 75.0; // I added as a global variable, as local returned NULL when I tried locally
    self.holderView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.height / 2 - self.boxSize / 2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - self.boxSize / 2,
                                       self.boxSize,
                                       self.boxSize);

    self.holderView.parentFrame = self.view.frame;
    self.holderView = [self.holderView initWithFrame:self.holderView.frame];    

    self.holderView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"addHolderView called");
    [self.view addSubview:self.holderView];
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You're never actually allocing and initing a holderView.  In the swift view controller, there is probably a point somewhere that does so.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going "backwards"...Swift to Objective-C. The call to `addHolderView()` is done in `viewDidAppear`. The Swift code works, the Obj-C doesn't.

Comment: I think I found part of the problem. There's a variable called on the Swift VC: `var holderView = HolderView(frame: CGRectZero)`. I didn't put the parameter on the one I declared. What would be the Obj-C equivalent for declaring that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code..

```
- (void)addHolderView {
    self.boxSize = 75.0; // I added as a global variable, as local returned NULL when I tried locally
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.height / 2 - self.boxSize / 2,
                                       self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - self.boxSize / 2,
                                       self.boxSize,
                                       self.boxSize);

    self.holderView = [[HolderView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];   
    self.holderView.parentFrame = self.view.frame;

    self.holderView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"addHolderView called");
    [self.view addSubview:self.holderView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That got me over the finish line!